# ngHandsontable: date-format not working in hot-column directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, handsontable, date-formatting

I try to format a date column as follows, both with the `settings` as well as the direct `date-format` attribute. Neither works. The column type is set to `date` and the provided data is of type `date`.

```
    <hot-column data="createdAt" title="'Date'" type="'date'"
          settings="{dateFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY', type: 'date'}"
          date-format="'DD/MM/YYYY'"
          correct-format="true"
          allow-empty="true" read-only></hot-column>
```

The date column would just not format. Other kinds of formatting, such as `numeric` types in the Severity column using `format`-attribute are working.

[image]

Complete table code:

```
  <hot-table read-only datarows="events" class="table table-bordered table-striped" row-headers="false" manual-column-resize="true">

    <hot-column data="createdAt" title="'Date'" type="'date'"
          settings="{dateFormat:'DD/MM/YYYY', type: 'date'}"
          date-format="'DD/MM/YYYY'"
          correct-format="true"
          allow-empty="true" read-only></hot-column>

    <hot-column data="eventType" title="'Event Type'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="user.displayName" title="'User'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="ipAddress" title="'IP Address'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="severity" title="'Severity'" type="'numeric'" format="'$ 0,0.00'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="eventMessage" title="'Message'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="" title="'Old data'"></hot-column>
    <hot-column data="" title="'New data'"></hot-column>
  </hot-table>
```

Using ngHandsontable 0.12.0, Handsontable 0.26.1.

Unfortunately there is not a single [demo](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable/tree/develop/demo) available using the `date-format` attribute.

My current workaround is to use a custom renderer and format the date via `moment()` in there.

Comment: Created a ticket here: https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable/issues/178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answers on https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable/issues/178:

> Hi @mathiasconradt, unfortunately date-format doesn't work in the same
>   manner than format (for numbers). This issue is related with
>   Handsontable itself and you can track changes [here](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3730).
>
> Workaround for this issue is call validateCells method after table
>   initialization. It forces the correction date format to another. I've
>   created demo [here](http://jsbin.com/nipagukali/1/edit?html,js,output).

Use `on-after-init` in the view:

```
<hot-table col-headers="true" datarows="ctrl.data" on-after-init="ctrl.onAfterInit">
```

and

```
  this.onAfterInit = function() {
    this.validateCells();
  }
```

in the controller.

Comment: How to add min date here....that the date pickers should not accept future date in angular.Please help